# How to prevent the user from repeating a character more than three times in the same word using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How to prevent the user from repeating a character more than three times in the same word
like this :
"hiii" its possible, but
"hiiii" not possible type in textbox,indicator is stopped.

I want like this
[site to add advertising](http://www.mstaml.com/manage/itemadd.php?v=1)
look the textbox : الإعلان *

Can you help me?

I tried this code :

```
<input name="text1" type="text" class="mult">

var mult = false,prev = 0;
$('.mult').keydown(function(e) {
if (!mult) {
mult = true;
prev = e.which;
setTimeout(function() {
mult = false;
}, 10000)
}
else if (prev != e.which) {
mult = false;
}
else {
return false;
}
});
```

But this prevent duplicate character one times with timeout.
I want to prevent user when duplicate character more than three times in same word without time.
I want when the user to type text and he wants to repeat the character in one word the indicator stops writing.

Comment: have you tried anything???

Comment: Yes, I tried but did not get the required

Comment: @Adnan7 When asked if you have tried anything, you are also expected to say what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use jQuery, you may use regex to test the string.

```
if (/(.)\1{3,}/.test(str)) {
    console.log('Not possible');
} else {
    console.log('possible');
}
```

Comment: thanks xdazz, but I want to allow the user to repeat a character just 3 times in one a word.using jquery

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery you can use:

```
$('. mult').keypress(function(){
  if (/(.)\1{2,}/.test($(this).val())) {
   return false;
  }
})
```

Here as working example:

```js
$('.limitRepeaters').keypress(function(){
  if (/(.)\1{2,}/.test($(this).val())) {
   return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="limitRepeaters">
```