# Prevent repeating characters in password

Tags: php, regex

```
$password = 'pwd3000!';

if(!preg_match('/^(?=.{4,31}$)(?!.*(.)\1{4}).   \w[\w.-]+\w$/', $password)){
   echo 'Your password is too easy'; 
} else {
   echo 'Your password is strong';
}
```

If a password has more than 4 repeating characters I want to echo 'Your password is too easy'.

Right now when I run the code, I get 'Your password it too easy'. But it's only 3 repeating characters in the string, not 4. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770148/how-to-prevent-the-user-from-repeating-a-character-more-than-three-times-in-the

Comment: Filter out repeating characters or *consecutive* repeating characters?

Comment: @castis consecutive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$password = "aaaabb";
if (preg_match('/(\w)\1{3,}/', $password)) {
   echo 'Your password is too easy'; 
} else {
    echo 'Your password is strong';
}
```

Output:

```
Your password is too easy
```